# $C_0(X)$ Characters

Tags: general-topology, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

This is a question on a Banach algebra setting.Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Consider $C_0(X)=\{f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{C} $, continuous :for every $r>0$ there exists $K_r\subseteq X$ compact with $|f(x)|\leq r$ for $x \in X\setminus K_r \}$

We know that this is a banach algebra with the sup norm and pointwise operations and the point is to identify the characters of this Banach Algebra.

My attempt is to consider a functional $\phi $ on the dual space which is identified by a finite total variation measure $m$ so as $\phi(f)=\int_{X}fdm$.
Now the multiplicativity (if that's a word) gives $ \phi(f^2)=\int_{X}f^2dm=(\int_{X}fdm)^2$ or $\int_{X}(f^2-(\int f dm)f)dm=0$...(now i need help).
I suspect that this functional should look like the fourier coefficient of the function multiplied by something...

Comment: $\chi_p(f) = f(p)$ is a character on any function space like this, where $p \in X$. For compact Hausdorff spaces these are all of them, with the $0$-function added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual of $C_0(X)$, where $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, is indeed the isomorphic to the space of regular Borel measures $\mu$ on $X$, where $\mu$ defines a functional $f \to \int fd\mu$ and all functionals are of this form. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), e.g.

A character is stronger, namely it's multiplicative. All non-zero ones of those correspond to all point-measures $\mu_p(A) = 1$ iff $p \in A$, for compact Hausdorff spaces $X$, i.e. all point evaluations on $C_c(X)$, as $\int fd\mu_p = f(p)$. This is not too hard to prove (I first saw it in Semadeni, *Banach spaces of continuous functions*). The proof I saw did not involve measures, though.

I think the same holds for $C_0(X)$, by considering $C_0(X)$ embedded into $C(\alpha(X))$ (where $\alpha(X) = X \cup \{\infty\}$ is the Alekandrov compactification of $X$), as all functions that vanish at $\infty$, and a character $\chi$ on $C_c(X)$ can be extended to one on $C(\alpha(X))$, using ideas like $\chi'(f) = \chi(f - f(\infty))$